# Schedule Notifications when App is closed

Tags: iphone

I have an application that picks up some data (numbers) from the iOS and increments the app counter [data from iOS are some values that are based on users interaction with the device]. I've kept a threshold of 100 in my app. Here when the user crosses the 100 limit, I alert the user with an AlertView.

The problem now is that if the app is closed, and if the iOS data crosses the 100 limit, I want the user to be notified.

I know the uses of NSLocalNotifications. But I want to know if I could schedule notifications when I app is closed?

**Note:**

- I do not wish to use APNS or any server based solution.
- I need a solution for iOS 4 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If app close, NSLocalNotifications work, but your processor can be applied only after the program will start. If not mistaken, you can catch it through the launchOptions in the applicationDelegate method  (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said that I know the use of NSLocalNotifications and the stuff you replied. I want to know if they can be scheduled when the app is closed i.e., add/register a new notification (of some future date) to the notification queue when the app is closed.